# Building bulkheads with steel studs

Tags: basement, framing

I'm looking to use steel studs for building bulkheads and lowering ceiling where needed, well because they are light and straight. I've never used steel studs, and on research I found there are essentially two components when building walls: tracks and studs.

Since this is my first time working with steel studs, few questions I want to run by:

1. For the purpose of building a bulkhead, I would only need tracks right? I don't need any electrical running through the tracks
2. What screws do I use to attach the tracks to joists? I know I can use self tapping for steel to steel, but is there any special screws I need for steel to wood?
3. How much weight can these tracks hold? I have a room where ductwork is right in the middle so was planning to just lower the ceiling altogether. Can I hang about 6 - 7 linear feet of drywall on steel tracks?
4. Can steel tracks touch ductwork? Or is there a minimum clearance?

Comment: What kind of "bulkhead" are you building?

Comment: around ductwork mostly. So will be an L shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1    For the purpose of building a bulkhead, I would only need tracks right? I don't need any electrical running through the tracks

You need both, the two products are different and not interchangeable.
tracks to go horizontally in the wall and studs to go vertically.

> What screws do I use to attach the tracks to joists? I know I can use self tapping for steel to steel, but is there any special screws I need for steel to wood?

It depends how strong you need, self tapping screws will work, or you can use self drilling wood screws for more strength.

> How much weight can these tracks hold?

It depends which ones you get.

> I have a room where ductwork is right in the middle so was planning to just lower the ceiling altogether. Can I hang about 6 - 7 linear feet of drywall on steel tracks?

There is a different product for that: ceiling channel (and hangers etc).

> Can steel tracks touch ductwork? Or is there a minimum clearance?

If the ductwork does not move it should be ok.